# Using ASP.NET Core tag helper asp-append-version without MVC or Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are using ASP.NET Core without MVC / Razor (our client is websockets based SPA) but have a need to bust the browser cache with file changes as Chrome isn't consistent with refreshing the cache when we update CSS/HTML/JS static files for our app.

The tag helper asp-append-version would be helpful however it appears it will only work if we convert our application to MVC or Razor which will be overkill for this function.

Giving it a try, I cannot locate any documentation about how to utilise it outside a MVC/Razor project and in the ConfigureServices function for setting up the webserver adding services.AddMvcCore does not seem to expose any functionality in the builder for the append-version.

A couple more questions:

1. If we are not using razor/MVC and assuming it can work this way, by manually adding tag helpers are we impacting the performance of our web server due to the overhead of the tag helper (eg. the web page is dynamically built for each request) - and we are better off using other more performant approaches to cache busting?
2. In our javascript application, we will dynamically load images / javascript based on user selection in the app by creating the relevant HTML tag and then appending to the DoM. Will asp-append-version work with this approach if we add it as a HTML attribute to the fragment before appending to the DoM?

Comment: So you have an asp.net core project that has multiple static files in wwwroot. Those files are your SPA application and might get updated. Also you have a static file named something like index.html that is your SPA root. Am I right?

Comment: @MrMoeinM, yes that is correct. The Microsoft documents sort of assume that razor or MVC is being used. Our app interacts with the server via websockets, and its unclear how or if asp-append-version can work, and adding it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have web server and single static file named app.js. Now consider these urls

```
http://example.com/app.js
http://example.com/app.js?v=1
http://example.com/app.js?v=2
```

These three urls point to same file and since it's a static file web server ignore the query string but because url are different browser consider these three different files.

What asp-append-version does is that append hash of the file as query string to file's url. This change file's url every time you change your file content.

Suppose we have something like this in your razor view

```
<img src="~/images/asplogo.png" asp-append-version="true">
```

it will render and generate html something like this

```
<img src="/images/asplogo.png?v=Kl_dqr9NVtnMdsM2MUg4qthUnWZm5T1fCEimBPWDNgM">
```

because asp-append-version calculate hash of file at backend you can not use it in static html. In fact all of razor tag helpers generate some html at backend and you need razor to use them.

If you have a few static files that change every time, you can manually change version number in your static html files. e.g.
after updating app.js change

```
<script src="~/app.js?v=0.1"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="~/app.js?v=0.2"></script>
```

in your index.html

Another way is you use razor to generate your html and use asp-append-version in your source code.

As you mentioned if you use js to load image or other js files you can have const version number that append at the end of each file's url and when you update your files you only need to change that const value.

```
const version = 0.2;
function loadjsfile(filename){
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename + "?v=" + version)
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
loadjsfile("app.js");
```

The downside of this method is that if you only update one single file and change version const all of urls will change and browser download every other files again.

Comment: Thanks MrMoeinM, your answer has highlighted the fact that Razor is needed to render the source to activate the tag helper function

Comment: why don't we have a asp-append-version in blazor? is this library any better than mvc?